# Calling variable from another event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a variable from another event, for example

```
     public void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var ccc = lblTicketsA;
    }

 public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
             ccc.text = "test";


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: You cannot 'call' a variable*.  To succeed at, and develop skills in, you have to learn to be very specific about your wording.  Many people will laugh this question off without trying further to understand it through your example.  You 'access' a variable.

* I know you can 'call' an accessor, but that's another day's nit-picking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `ccc` an instance field like this:

```
private SomeType ccc;

public void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ccc = lblTicketsA;
}

public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.ccc.text = "test"
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```